# Multiple Recurrence Rule and Exception Rule in Icalendar

Tags: icalendar, multiple-instances, recurrence

I have to use multiple recurrence rules and exception rules in icalendar file, as I have read in specification ([`RFC 2445`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt)) that multiple instances of recurrence rule and exception rule can be specified to define more sophisticated recurrence sets. Does this mean that I can write multiple lines of RRule in icalendar file?

```
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=TU,TH
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=6,7
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=18;COUNT=10;BYMONTHDAY=10,11,12,13,14
```

Does anyone know how can I write multiple instances of recurrence rule and exception rule?

Answer (score 0):

you can but RFC 5545 (which obsoletes 2445) states

> the final recurrence set is generated by gathering all of the start DATE-TIME values generated by any of the specified "RRULE" and "RDATE" properties, and then excluding any start DATE-TIME values specified by "EXDATE" properties.

however given you example it looks like you want might be better defined by something like:

> RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=6,7;BYDAY=TU,TH;BYMONTHDAY=10,11,12,13,14;COUNT=10

(though this is a guess as your desired outcome is not explicit)